# SharePoint 2010 Filtering list results with auto-complete text search

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a SharePoint 2010 aspx page with several linked lists. At the top is our 'core table' that users can select from, and it updates the connected lists below. 
I'm attempting to create a search box, with auto-complete functionality, that allows users to sort/filter/search through the list of names in the core table, which will allow the user to select a single result and have the linked tables update.

I've tried several things with no luck, including HTML form (requires explicit text), and some options i've found here and other online resources, unsuccessfully. i think the reliance on the linked lists is causing hiccups. also, the core table contains hundreds of entries so pagination is a requirement. the default view contains groupings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, there seems to be a great deal of Autocomplete solutions, but [this](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) one, SPServices library, is by far the best. It is not just for Autocomplete, it works for a load of other things. Be sure to read the whole documentation on this.

My guess is that setting up a basic regular Filter Web Part (or BDC Filter), linking it to the core table, and then applying autocomplete functionality on the filter search might do the trick.

Some examples on how to apply the jQuery code can be found on the internet (I would post them, but my low reputation allows only 2 links) and, from the author of the SPServices library Marc Anderson`s blog, [here](http://sympmarc.com/2011/08/24/using-spservices-with-jqueryuis-autocomplete-function-on-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint/).

Personally, this simple code did the trick for me:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('ctl00_m_g_b3f08547_27a4_484c_938a_f92864c47b7a_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl').title = 'Test';

        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({ 
            sourceList: "TestList", //The name of your List
            sourceColumn: "Title", //The name of the column you are taking the data FROM
            columnName: "Test", // The name of the column/textbox you want to apply the Autocomplete TO
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 3,
            slideDownSpeed: 50,
            debug: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that the code works with the *Single line of text* column type and the `title` property. Now, my filter did not
have any `title` property, but it did have an `id` one, so I just added it, as seen in the first line of code.

Btw, there is a StackExchange forum dedicated to [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/), so you can post this or any other questions there.